# With Log4j2, how to filter out certain stack trace lines matching a particular regex?

Tags: spring, log4j2

I want to get rid of irrelevant lines from Log4j2's output.

I'm already using the `filters` option of my `xEx` conversion pattern to filter out the output produced by packages such as reactor or netty, but there are still other needless lines in the output that cannot be filtered out using the aforementioned option.

For instance, I would like Log4j to ignore the classes generated by Spring CGLIB :

```java
com.myapp.exception.MyException: Error while trying to get my thing
    at com.myapp.api.cache.MyCache.getMyThing(MyCache.java:44) ~[!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... suppressed 13 lines
    at com.myapp.api.cache.MyCache$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getMyThing(<generated>) ~[!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... suppressed 12 lines
```

I tried using a RegexFilter matching the two dollar signs like below, but it does not work, as this filter seems to operate only on the message, and not on the exception stack trace :

```
  RegexFilter:
    - regex: ".*\\$\\$.*"
      onMatch: DENY
      onMismatch: ACCEPT
```

Comment: i think this is a job for the appenders, not the filters...however i dont have the api right here so cannot confirm 100%

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel Thanks. That's also my impression. I tried using `%replace{%xEx{filters(...}{.*\\$\\$.*[\\r]+\\n}{}`, and the extra lines are indeed removed from the current exception stack trace, but the package filter is no longer applied on the stack trace of the causing throwable.